# Multiple s/// commands in vim visual mode

Tags: vim

I want to:

- Select multiple lines (<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>)
- Insert leading spaces on each selected line
- Remove trailing spaces (if any) on each selected line

I'd like to do the changes in one step. Here's how I can do it in multiple steps:

```
:'<,'>s/^/    /
gv
:'<,'>s/ *$//
```

This is the only way I've found to do it in one step:

```
:'<,'>s/^/    /|:exec "norm gv:s/ *$//^@"
```

where `^@` is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd>

Is there a better way to do this. I'm interested in a general solution for multiple `s///` commands in visual mode more than one about leading and trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it all in one substitution:

```
:s/\(.\{-}\)\s*$/    \1/
```

We capture the "meat" of the line and add the starting whitespace while removing the trailing space.

Multiple substitutions:

```
:s/^/    /|'<,'>s/\s*$//
```

We use explicitly use `'<,'>` as our visual range (See `:h '<`). We can also use `*` as short hand for `'<,'>`. e.g. `:*s/\s*$//`

Comment: `:'<,'>s/^/    /|'<,'>s/ *$//` or `:*s/^/    /|*s/ *$//` are exactly what I was looking for! Thanks! The problem was that I wasn't specifying the range for each command.

Answer (score 1):

Here; it's best (i.e. shorter and faster) to do both deletions at once (as per @PeterRincker's answer). In general, you don't need to reselect; the `'<,'>` will persist even when visual mode has been left (until you do another selection). So, this would work:

```
:'<,'>s/^/    / | '<,'>s/ *$//
```

Comment: That's exactly what I posted earlier in my comment to Peter Rincker's answer and is essentially the same as part of his answer.